# App-Store Review Guideline: Responsive website in web-view

Tags: ios, app-store

I have a responsive blogging website which works pretty well across all iOS and Android browsers. Now I want to create a native App for my website.

I don't have the resources to design my App from scratch and create mobile-APIs to be consumed by my App. So I am thinking about opening my website in a web-view. This would not be it though, I will be implementing the features like 'take a blog offline for reading later', notifications etc.

So, what are the chances that it would not get rejected by the App-Store®?

Comment: Given that you added a few features that can't be done in mobile Safari, the only way to know is to submit the app for review.  Make sure you test the app in airplane mode.

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

> Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected.

Despite the fact, your app will provide "offline content" (which can be [accessed](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200294) by default Safari browser) I think you app will be rejected.

> Safari will save the link and the webpage so you can read it, even when you're offline.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want to send push-notifications to my viewers which works on desktop Safari but not on mobile safari.